# how to select rows from a dataframe between two lists of index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python, and I'm working on a very raw dataset.

lets say I have two index list x and y,

x is like 1,10, 20, 25, 37
y is like 6,15, 24, 29, 39

I know how to select rows based on 1 index list, such as:

```
df.iloc[x]
```

but I was wondering if there is any way I could select rows between two index list?

something like:

```
df.iloc[x:y]
```

so, from above, I can get all the rows between 1:6, 10:15

Thank you so much

P.S after I get all the rows between two list, there will be many dataframes I guess. So how could I loop that?

so far I can think of,

```
for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2):
pd.merge(df.iloc[x:y])
```

but it's wrong:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
x = [1, 10, 20, 25, 37]
y = [6, 15, 24, 29, 39]

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    # select row from i to j and then select all columns.
    print(df.iloc[i:j, :])
```

If instead of printing you wanna concat all df's use:

```
result = pd.concat([df.iloc[i:j, :] for i, j in zip(x, y)])
```

NOTE:  You can use `iloc` like shown below, and you can also play with step size if you want:

```
dataframe.iloc[start_index:end_index,start_col:end_col]
```

Comment: :( sorry, im new, your method is correct shown, but whenever i tried for i, j in zip(x, y):
    df = df.iloc[i:j, :]) , i can only get only one df, instead of multiple df, like shown when using print, i was wondering if something i did wrong?

Comment: This above method doesn't store the dataframes, it just prints them. Creating a list of dataframes (appending every iteration of the for loop and running `pd.concat` at the end) can create the full dataframe.

Comment: so far im thinking for i, j in zip(x, y): pd.concat(df.iloc[i:j, :])), but i got error: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: @Kow that will throw an error. You need to check the documentation of `pd.concat`. You can't just pass one single dataframe to the function. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it like `df.iloc[x[i]:y[j]]`, where **i** and **j** can be used as indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that , code will be like `df.iloc[x[0]:y[0]]`.
Index for lists x and y can be variables if you have some logic to run.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I guess I need to use something like loop? but I'm new to python, how i get so far is for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2):
    df.iloc[x:y], but i dont know how to proceed:(

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of boolean indexing, the following can be done:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() # your dataframe here

x = [1, 10, 20, 25, 37]
y = [6, 15, 24, 29, 39]

indices = np.zeros(len(df.index))

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    indices[i:j] = 1

print(df.loc[indices])
```

Comment: emm. sorry, the result is not correctly shown. maybe because im new to python:P

Comment: Do you have a variable `df` for your dataframe and initialize lists `x` and `y`?

Comment: emm, sorry, i dont understand